# jQuery AJAX ready on <h1>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a website which should heavily rely on ajax. But I'm facing a problem which I cannot find a solution to online.

**I'll now shamelessly post my (stripped) function to completely fetch a page.**

```
function loadTemplate(name, replaceWholePage = true){
    $.when( $.ajax({ url: "./templates/{0}/{0}.html".format(name), error: function() { console.error(  "Could not load HTML file of template '{0}'!".format(name)); }}),
            $.ajax({ url: "./templates/{0}/{0}.css".format(name), error: function() {  console.error("Could not load CSS file of template '{0}'!".format(name));  }}),
            $.ajax({ url: "./templates/{0}/{0}.js".format(name), error: function() {   console.error("Could not load JS file of template '{0}'!".format(name));   }}) )
    .then(function(html, css, js) {
        var _css = "\n<style>\n" + css[0] + "\n</style>";
        var _js = "\n<script>\n" + js[0] + "\n</script>";

        if(replaceWholePage) {
            $("#content").empty();
        }

        $("#content").append(html[0]);
        $("#content").append(_css);
        //$("#content").append(_js);
    });
}
```

You see the line where it appends the js file is commented. But somehow the site still gets the js. When I comment that line out, my js code isn't actually twice in the document, but still gets called twice.

Comment: If content of ```js[0]``` is not a string then I believe it will get parsed as normal javascript?

Comment: The thing is that I don't append the js file and still everything works .. I'd like to know why. I checked html[0] and css[0], none of them have any js code in them.

Comment: Its strange, when I'm printing something to the console, the file that shouldn't be included shows up under a strange [name](https://i.imgur.com/34YbWAf.png).

Comment: I believe this line ```$.ajax({ url: "./templates/{0}/{0}.js".format(name), error:...``` makes an ajax request immediately and results are processed, regardless whether the results are being used in ```.then``` later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Varinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497815/varinder) stated, jQuery automatically recognised the fetched file as javascript and executed it. Setting the `dataType` to `"text"` in the call fixed it!

Thanks